# Wanted to embed Netflix Hystrix into an existing SMSC project

Tags: hystrix, netflix

I'm trying to use Netflix Hystrix open source API in an existing project to handle fault tolerance and Circuit Breaker implementation. I have referred some websites, but I couldn't get complete information about the implementation.
 How can i invoke the below Hystrix program from my service class and what object it returns i'm unable to understand.
Below is the sample program about Hystrix.

Can anybody please help me to do this.

```
public class CommandHelloWorld extends HystrixCommand<String> {

    private final String name;

    public CommandHelloWorld(String name) {
        super(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("ExampleGroup"));
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected String run() {
        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    }

    public static class UnitTest {

        @Test
        public void testSynchronous() {
            assertEquals("Hello World!", new CommandHelloWorld("World").execute());
            assertEquals("Hello Bob!", new CommandHelloWorld("Bob").execute());
        }

        @Test
        public void testAsynchronous1() throws Exception {
            assertEquals("Hello World!", new CommandHelloWorld("World").queue().get());
            assertEquals("Hello Bob!", new CommandHelloWorld("Bob").queue().get());
        }

        @Test
        public void testAsynchronous2() throws Exception {
            Future<String> fWorld = new CommandHelloWorld("World").queue();
            Future<String> fBob = new CommandHelloWorld("Bob").queue();
            assertEquals("Hello World!", fWorld.get());
            assertEquals("Hello Bob!", fBob.get());
        }     
    }
}
```